# Highling radio buttons with JS

Tags: javascript, radio-button, highlight

Here is my radio button:

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" id="chk1" name="chooseSupp" onclick="change(this);">
    Chosen Supplier
</label>
```

Here is my Javascript which highlights the cell:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function change(obj) {
    var tr=obj.parentNode.parentNode;
    tr.style.backgroundColor=(obj.checked)? 'red' : 'transparent';
  }
</script>
```

The problem is, when I click on a radio button, it highlights okay but then when I click on a different radio button, it is also highlighted, but the highlighting on the first button does not go away.

My radio button is in a loop, not sure if that is relevant to any possible solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function change(obj) {
      var tr=obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
      var tbl = tr.parentNode;
      var inputs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for(var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++)
          inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
      tr.style.backgroundColor=(obj.checked)? 'red' : 'transparent';
    }
```

Make all other inputs transparent first. then apply your style to the new one.

you could alternatively check if the other inputs are checked to, like you do for the current input. That would be usefull if you work with checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks. Is it also possible to 'clear' the radio button, if they click on it by mistake for example?

Comment: what do you mean? to deselect all radios? Radios are not made for not be checked at all. As if you send things to the server by "name" then something should be selected. like a drop down menu. You cannot unselect all in a drop down. The common way is to supply an empty field. This could be done with your radios. Like "please select: None | This | Other".

Comment: Okay thanks. So how would I add this extra 'None Selected' button **without** it having the highlighting?

Comment: just mark it somehow. give it a special classname, like "no-highlight" and check in the "change" function if the element has "no-highlight" class, if it has, do nothing, if it doesnt apply the background color. Btw a better approach would be to make everything with classes, not inline-styles. just assign or unassign a class. like "highlight" or for the none-selected "no-highlight highlight". in your css you would then make .highlight {..showhighlight..}, .no-highlight.highlight {..dont show highlight...}